# Force pyramid zoom level on any WMS, WMTS or XYZ?

Tags: qgis-3

Is there a way to lock the view to any tileset level regardless of the scale, e.g remain at zoom level 12 whether the scale is 1:250000 or 1:62500, so that features like text and paths appear at different size rather than adapting to the view ?

I'm on QGIS 3.10

Comment: That runs the risk of breaking the server and the client so I expect not

Comment: it sure seems like a pandora's box but if some safety measures are implemented (e.g. preventing loading more than n tiles or x pixels), I don't see a reason not to have this.